# Access SELECT Where Field More than X Days ago

Tags: sql, ms-access

This query appears to be returning ALL rows and not just those more than 3 days old (ie the date in Created On field)

```
SELECT * FROM Master WHERE [Created On] < (Date()-3);
```

I don't see what is wrong with it.

EDIT - this worked as expected (sorry my question was badly worded)

```
SELECT * FROM Master WHERE [Created On] > (Date()-3);
```

Just changed the < to > ie all records that are more recent than 3 days ago.

Comment: Which DBMS using..?

Comment: @mansoor It says ms access. Check the tags

Comment: What is the type of `Created on` column?

Comment: Hope you are not trying to compare Date() with an integer.

Comment: Created on is dd/mm/yyyy Date/Time

Comment: Ooops, I had the > the wrong way round!

Comment: @davidjwest - So, was this answered (in that it was a typo) or are you still not getting the desired results?

Comment: No, it is correct, my mistake, shall I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your SELECT command and it's apparently correct. In my case the query worked perfect. Try to execute this select to see the result of the `(Date() -3)` from three days ago.
For example:

```
SELECT Date(), Date() -3, *
FROM Master
WHERE [Created On]<(Date()-3);
```

Follow the link with more information about Date() function for MS-Access: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762